# Why does speccy say that virtualization is not supported, when it is enabled in the bios?

Tags: virtualization

I have an AMD FX 6300, and I have virtualization enabled in the BIOS (I checked it twice) but Speccy says it's disabled.

I am on Windows 8.1 and can run VM's on Hyper-V fine, is this something I need to be concerned about?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: If everything works fine I can't imagine you need to worry. My Speccy shows this as enabled, but I have gone out my way to turn it on. Maybe Speccy only registers specific active visualization types.

Comment: I should have added to the question, Virtualbox only has the option to install 32-bit OS', but the Windows Phone 8 emulator works. I'm a little confused.

Comment: It also could be a bug in Speccy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86 CPUs don't support nested virtualization, so if virtualization is working and in use, virtualization is not available. Once something uses the virtualization, you now have a virtual CPU that doesn't itself support virtualization.

Comment: Not entirely correct. Although x86 CPUs don't support nested virtualization by themselves, you can still tell the L0 hypervisor to expose VMX to its guests (either specific ones or all of them). This, however, relies entirely on the L0 hypervisor as it has to intercept and redirect any hypercalls made in L2 guests to the appropriate L1 hypervisor.